# No classes in war maven

Tags: java, maven

I'm pretty new in using og maven, an I got stuck. mvn clean install does not generate classes :(

I'm using the following code in my pom :

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
      <configuration>
        <webXml>WebContent\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
        <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
       </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please read the [usage page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/usage.html) first, it will show the expected folder structure. 
So java sources are expected in src/main/java.
BTW: If you still want to use `WebContent`, set the [warSourceDirectory](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#warSourceDirectory) to `WebContent`, remove all other configuration.

Answer (score 1):

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.6</target>
            <optimize>true</optimize>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <webResources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
            </webResources>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```